# Sudo on UNIX. does not prompt for password for switching to other user

Tags: sudo

I configured sudo. But when i login to a user with sudo, it will prompt me for my password. However if I su to other user it will not ask me for a password. How do i tackle this?

Please see the below log

```
$ id
uid=228(sudotst) gid=204(L1Group) //Logged in as sudotst user
$
$
$ bash
bash-4.3$
bash-4.3$ sudo su - kshah    //i switch to user kshah and it prompts me for 
                               password which is expected
Password:
$
$ id
uid=216(kshah) gid=203(admin) groups=1(staff)
$
$
$ sudo su - alakde                //Now when I switch to other user why it does not ask me for a password.
$
$ id
uid=210(alakde) gid=1(staff) groups=204(L1Group)
$
```

Comment: Not answerable without knowing the sudo configuration and the users that are used.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` caches the password, by default for 5 minutes on Debian, 15 minutes on Ubuntu (these are just examples). If you use `sudo`, you asked for the password. If you use it again within the configured cache time you are not asked for the password, because it still remembers it. If you wait until the configured time expires between the `sudo` uses you will be asked for the password again.

Another possibility in your case: You first `su` to a user that is in the group `admin`. It is possible that users of the admin group are allowed to use `sudo` without a password. Hence no password when you switch to the third user. To know that for sure  we need to see your `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: is there a way to change the wait time?

Comment: Of course. It's documented in `man sudoers`. But I suspect the second possibility is more plausible.